# ComboBox Items For Origin and Destination Case in C# That Have DataSource From Database

Tags: c#, database, combobox

Is it possible to add `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` into a second `ComboBox` that were not selected in the first `ComboBox` in C# ?

I Have ComboBox1 DataSource From Database.

After I Selected One of Any Items in ComboBox1,
I Want ComboBox2 Items Automatically Added, But Without ComboBox1 Selected Item. (Included With ValueMember)

Example :

```
ComboBox1 :  
Value Member   |   Display Member 
---------------|----------------- 
1              |   English  
2              |   American  
3              |   Australia
```

If I Select:

> 1 | English

Then, ComboBox2 Should Just Display :

```
Value Member   |   Display Member
---------------|-----------------
2              |   American  
3              |   Australia
```